# Stack with AddUniqueItem

Tags: c#, stack

I have a behavior I need to implement with a Tab Control:

Each time a tab is selected, `Stack.Push();` the deselected tab. When a user close the selected tab, go to the tab returned by `Stack.Pop();` and so on. When another tab than the selected, simply `Stack.Pop();`.

I presently use a `Stack` that contains all the deselected tabs. What I would like is the **capability to remove all existing copies of a Pushed tab within the stack, then proceed to the actual `Stack.Push()`.** Is the described behavior possible with a Stack, knowing it don't support random access ?

Comment: Stacks are LIFO so you can only access the top element. You probably need to use a List

Comment: List don't come with Pop(), and Push(). I was hoping for an elegant solution, and List was my last choice.

Comment: Even with a list, searching the whole thing for duplicates and then removing them all is a rather inefficient operation.

Comment: @Francis.Beauchamp Have an extension method to List<T> that implements Push and Pop. This is really a case of using the good tools for your problems. And Servy is right, it would be inefficient to use a list too.

Comment: Rather than removing duplicates add code to stop them from being added in the first place. Preventing the queuing/pushing/adding of a dupe is linear time, removing them after they're added is O(n^2) and you'll still have to do it after every new item is added.

Comment: Problem is, you don't want a stack. Stacks don't allow access to the middle or bottom elements. *You should only use a stack if you want to read LIFO*

Comment: I think that with List I could do a RemoveAll(predicates). This is basically what I would like with the LIFO behavior of a stack.

Comment: @Francis.Beauchamp And that method is not particularly efficient.  It's easy to code, but it doesn't scale well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, you just need to remove and then re-add all of the items in the stack.

```
public static void PushUnique<T>(this Stack<T> stack, T item
    , IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = null)
{
    comparer = comparer ?? EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
    var otherStack = new Stack<T>();
    while (stack.Any())
    {
        var next = stack.Pop();
        if (!comparer.Equals(next, item))
            otherStack.Push(next);
    }

    foreach (var next in otherStack)
        stack.Push(next);
    stack.Push(item);
}
```

Comment: I was actually trying to implement it as I am writing this comment. Thanks for taking the time to help me out, it works great.

Comment: @Francis.Beauchamp Just understand that you're completely rebuilding the stack on each add (no matter what), which is expensive, so this shouldn't be used for a non-trivially sized collection.

Comment: My tab control will never have more than one tab by functionality, which is ~ 20.